# PHP complex Sprintf

Tags: php, printf

I'm doing a system to log users' actions, such as the purchases it made, friends it added, among anothers. For example, when a user purchase some products, the following message should appear in your profile:

> Foo bought the products A, B, C, D and F.

I could save the whole string in the database, but the site will have more than one language, which will make unviable keep a record for each language. My idea is to have a string with the template of the action taken and pass it to the `sprintf` function, however, the amount of products may change, so the number of arguments as well. In this situation, how should I proceed?

**Edit #1:** My question is not about the database schema, the schema I'm using is this: [Databases: Making a Log of actions, how to handle various references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989100/databases-making-a-log-of-actions-how-to-handle-various-references/2032042#2032042), The question is how to make a string to be used with sprintf that can receive as many arguments as needed.
Something like this: `"%s bought the products [magic here]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a unique code for each action. Store the action in a number of fields in a table called `log`:

```
user      action      products
-----------------------------------
Foo       BUY         A|B|C|D
```

Map `BUY` to human-readable descriptions in your application as required.

You could separate out the individual products if required, to achieve full normalisation... though if you don't need anything more with them and their representations are concise IDs (with no `|` in them!) then tokenisation will do fine.

Comment: Yep, I'm using this schema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989100/databases-making-a-log-of-actions-how-to-handle-various-references/2032042#2032042, but the question is how to make a string to be used with sprintf that can receive as many arguments as needed.

Comment: sprintf() doesn't work that way. Build the string externally and then pass it into sprintf as a single `%s`.

Comment: @Marc B I thought there would be another way to do this, but apparently the way you're saying is the only way. :(

Comment: sprintf's are `take X, format it as Y` type things. None of its arguments allow `take four values A,B,C,D and conver them to a single Y`. They're 1:1 conversions only. If you want many:1, you'll have to do it externally.